# Google VM with a postfix and mailman issue

Tags: postfix, google-cloud-platform, mailman

I have a VM with Google running postfix 3.5.8 and mailman 2.1.29.  The original that Google generated was similar to this: "new-host.c.agile-being-111111.internal".  I've now reset the server to its final name i.e. host.org but the original Google generate name is embedded into all email and urls associated with mailman.  The problem appears to be in the list's config.pck where dumpdb produces two lines:

'host_name': 'new-host.c.agile-being-111111.internal',

'web_page_url': 'http://new-host.c.agile-being-111111.internal/mailman/',

I believe this is fixable with bin/withlist -l -r fix_url listname -u host.org
(where host.org represents my final host name)

But I am at a loss on how to make this happen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems reasonable. So what happened when you ran withlist?

Answer (score 1):

@Michael - I can't say as as it was earlier in the day.  So I repeated the exact command in order to replicate the problem/error except this time it worked.  I used the exact syntax from my .bash_history.  Doing a dumpdb on the config.pck produces the correct 'host_name' and 'web_page_url'.

Thx